# Loading 3d model into OpenGL scene

Tags: c++, api, qt, opengl

I need to load and store 3d models in my project and render them in an OpenGL scene. I can choose type of models to be exported. dwg, max, step and some other formats are available. Just found that OpenGL is low-level API and does not contain any facilities to parse 3d model files. I'm looking for some library/API to translate a 3d file structure into OpenGL primitives (or some other raw data) and store them back in a file with specified format.

For example I would like to load a [step](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_for_the_Exchange_of_Product_model_data) file, rotate and scale some objects, and then save modified file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that Assimp could be what you are looking for: http://assimp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: seems to be right way... I'm going to try it.  Thanks ;)

Comment: The only problem with AssImp is that in debug mode it's incredibly slow, mostly due to its heavy use of standard libraries, which themselves have lots of debug checking switched on by default.  I use AssImp, but I tend to use it with an app in the tool chain that exports meshes, materials and animations in my own format.  Still, it's pretty comprehensive and seems to work OK, so it's recommended :).

Comment: assimp is included in the recently release Qt3D package (see http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2012/04/11/qt-3d-and-qt5-qt4-news-and-releases/)

Comment: Robinson: I agree, the debug builds are a bit slow (this is an issue we're working on). Currently, if you use the debug DLL builds on Windows you can manually configure the standard libs with less debug checking if you want.

Answer (score 4):

C++ 3ds loader:

http://www.spacesimulator.net/wiki/index.php?title=Tutorials:3ds_Loader